# Unrelated content is displaying in my webpage

Tags: safari

I am using Safari MAC system here, some content is displaying in my webpage which is not related to the webpage and I have not placed anything related to this content in the page. And also getting this content in only MAC-Safari browser.

Can someone tell me why I am getting unnecessary content in the webpage in MAC Safari[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9Y5U.png).

Thanks
Sateesh

Comment: in the image what all is the unwanted content? and also if you can provide a link to check this willbe nice to look into the issue

Comment: Total content in the image is unwanted content, that is part of content which is displaying in the web page.